# Database Inspection is not showing inside App Inspection

Tags: android, android-studio, database-inspector

I am trying to open Database Inspection inside App Inspection but It is not showing anything just leaving
`Deploy your app to a device running API level 26 or higher`

What I am using?

- API level 28
- Android 2020.3.1

It does even not work after running the app

Here is the screenshot

[click to see the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1PU7.jpg)

Please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Database inspector only shows when a database is open. A way to achieve this is to put a breakpoint where a writable database is constructed.